# iOS Dropbox Sync API - Pushing to empty view controller when linking accounts

Tags: ios, dropbox-api

I launch the dropbox view controller to link the user's account using the `"[[DBAccountManager`sharedManager`] linkFromController:self];"` call. Then when the I enter anything into the fields, two new views are pushed which only contains an activity indicator. I have waited at that screen for a length of time which I deemed enough to determine nothing was or is going to happen. I can press back and go back two views to the username and password entry screen, but the same issue happens as soon as I enter anything into the fields.

I double checked to confirm that I did not have an observer on any `UITextField` objects which could be impacting this action. I would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by clearing the content and settings for the simulator.  I was never able to reproduce this issue on a device.  I'm not sure however what the cause of the issue was to begine with